# Boids in python; calculating distance between two boids

Tags: python, vector, distance, boids

I'm trying to program the behaviour of birds in flight with boids in Python. I haven't found much yet but currently i'm stuck on the function defining the distance between two boids. It has to be calculated with the formula (a,b) = sqrt( (a_x - b_x)^2 + (a_y - b_y)^2) ) where a and b are the two vectors between which i have to calcualte the distance, a_x and b_x are the x-components of the vectors and a_y and b_y are the y-components. I get an error about the indices in the formula. I've tried solving in in a number of ways but i just can't figure out how to do it...

Here is what i've got so far. I'm very new to programming so I only know the basics and i'm not sure if the rest of what i've got is ok.;

```
WIDTH = 1000            # WIDTH OF SCREEN IN PIXELS
HEIGHT = 500            # HEIGHT OF SCREEN IN PIXELS
BOIDS = 20              # NUMBER OF BOIDS IN SIMULATION
SPEED_LIMIT = 500       # FOR BOID VELOCITY
BOID_EYESIGHT = 50      # HOW FAR A BOID CAN LOOK
WALL = 50               # FROM SIDE IN PIXELS
WALL_FORCE = 100        # ACCELERATION PER MOVE


from math import sqrt
import random
X = 0
Y = 1
VX = 2
VY = 3

def calculate_distance(a,b):
    a = []
    b = []
    for x in range (len(a)):
        for y in range (len(b)):
            distance = sqrt((a[X] - b[X])**2 + (a[Y] - b[Y])**2)
            return distance


boids = []

for i in range(BOIDS):
    b_pos_x = random.uniform(0,WIDTH)
    b_pos_y = random.uniform(0,HEIGHT)
    b_vel_x = random.uniform(-100,100)
    b_vel_y = random.uniform(-100,100)
    b = [b_pos_x, b_pos_y, b_vel_x, b_vel_y]

    boids.append(b)

    for element_1 in range(len(boids)):
        for element_2 in range(len(boids)):
            distance = calculate_distance(element_1,element_2)
```

Comment: in calculate_distance you set a and b to an empty list and then use a for loop ... you probably don't want that.

Comment: You have (capital) `X` and `Y` defined but inside your `calculate_distance` `for` loops you are creating `x` and `y` which go unused. Perhaps you meant to use those?

Comment: "I get an error about the indices in the formula" What's the error? When I run the code above, I don't get any errors.

Comment: I would suggest you post this on Code Review once you get something running. I think you will find it helpful

Comment: To expand on Michael Keijers answer, since you say you are new, those first two lines of `calculate_distance` are wiping out all of your input data.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

- You are not passing in any boid data into your function, just the
  indices `element_1` and `element_2`. So `calculate_distance` does not know
  anything about the boids.
- Even if you were passing in boid data you are assigning empty lists to `a` and `b` , which means the inside of your loop is never executed.

You want something like:

```
for element_1 in range(len(boids)):
    for element_2 in range(len(boids)):
        distance = calculate_distance(boids[element_1],boids[element_2])
```

and then

```
def calculate_distance(a,b):
    return sqrt((a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2)
```